# Get Object from Objects Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-4

i have two Models, first:

```
class Tutorial extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'tutorials'; 

public function rating()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Rating');
}   

}
```

and:

```
class Rating extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'ratings';

public  $timestamps = false;

public function tutorial()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Tutorial');
}   
}
```

now in my controller i have this:

```
public function get_index() {

    $tutorials = tutorial::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->with('rating')
        ->paginate(25);

    return View::make('site/home/index')->with('tutorials', $tutorials);
}
```

So how do i get all ratings from one tutorial in my View?!

EDIT:

Now i have this:

```
public function ratings()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Rating');
}   

public function getRating()
{
    // Grab the ratings from this tutorial
    $ratings = $this->ratings;
    $summedRatings = 0;

    // Loop through them all and add them together
    foreach($ratings as $rating)
    {
        console.log($rating->value);
        $summedRatings += $rating->value;
    }

    // Return the calculated average
    return $summedRatings / count($ratings);
}

public function get_index() {

    $tutorials = Tutorial::with('ratings')
        ->with('user')
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->paginate(25);

    return View::make('site/home/index')->with('tutorials', $tutorials);
}
```

and in my View:

```
@foreach($tutorials as $tutorial)
<span>{{$tutorial->rating}}</span>

@endforeach
```

But all my < span >´s are empty!

UPDATE: if i do this:

```
@foreach($tutorials as $tutorial)

            @foreach($tutorial->ratings as $rate)

            <span>{{$rate->value}}</span>

            @endforeach
```

everything is good....So what´s wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, as far as naming conventions go, to make things easier to understand: The `rating()` method within your tutorial method should be called `ratings()`, so when you grab your ratings, it will look better (`$tutorial->ratings`)

After renaming this, in your view, while looping through the array of $tutorials, you could access the ratings of each one like this:

```
foreach($tutorials as $tutorial)
{
    $ratings = $tutorial->ratings;
}
```

Which would retrieve the ratings object of each.

What you should know is that **you can create properties for your model if you need to return the calculation of the ratings, instead of the ORM objects**

For example, if each rating is a number from 1-5 in the ratings table stored in an `amount` column, you can do this to set the average of each rating as a property:

```
class Tutorial extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'tutorials'; 

public function ratings()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Rating');
}  

public function getRating()
{
    // Grab the ratings from this tutorial
    $ratings = $this->ratings;
    $summedRatings = 0;

    // Loop through them all and add them together
    foreach($ratings as $rating)
    {
        $summedRatings += $rating->amount;
    }

    // Return the calculated average
    return $summedRatings / count($ratings);
}

}
```

Then in your view, you can echo out the property as if it were part of the database

```
foreach($tutorials as $tutorial)
{
    echo $tutorial->rating;
}
```

Comment: that doesn´t work! Gives me Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::rating()

Comment: This may be due to me jumping between Laravel 3/4 and forgetting where camel casing is. Try change `public function get_rating()` to `public function getRating()`, and that should fix it.

Comment: It doesn't make sense as to why it is throwing an error on the \Query\Builder class, as it should be a Tutorial object since it has already been retrieved from the database... Would you mind updating your code as to where it is at now if you have changed anything else?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the platform you're site is on you should always use the correct case.

```
$tutorials = tutorial::orderBy(...) // Wrong

$tutorials = Tutorial::orderBy(...) // Correct
```

To eager load the ratings you should always declare your 'with' method before anything else.

```
$tutorials = Tutorial::with('rating')
                 ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                 ->paginate(25);
```

This has, for some reason, been left out of the L4 docs.

In your view you can now access the rating with this

```
foreach($tutorials as $tutorial)
{
    echo $tutorial->rating->{rating table column name};
}
```

Comment: +1 for correct casing & the eager loading tip, I hadn't realised where that method must be placed before...

Comment: it gives me a 500 Internal Server Error!

Comment: well do you have the rating property of the `Eloquent Tutorial` model? var dump it. If it isn't there then you're relationships are not configured correctly with your DB.

Comment: What does it mean var dump it?!

Comment: `var_dump($tutorial)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35196/discussion-between-chrizstone-and-david-barker)

Comment: Im sorry chrizstone I don't have time to continue this at the moment. I'm flying to Thailand in a few hours. Ill check again when I get there.